# Unity 2021.3.21f1 LTS Parkour coding issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently attempting to program a Parkour system in Unity 2021 LTS, but I'm currently running into an issue when attempting to program a Match Targeting algorithm. Below is my script that is complaining (known as 'ParkourController.cs'), followed by the error that shows up:

ParkourController.cs:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

// NOTE: Make sure that different actions are alligned in the parkourActions list in order of their heights, regardless of property 
// (otherwise it'll not work properly!)

public class ParkourController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] List<ParkourAction> parkourActions;

    private EnvironmentScanner environmentScanner;
    private Animator animator;
    private bool inAction;
    private PlayerController playerController;

    private void Awake()
    {
        environmentScanner = GetComponent<EnvironmentScanner>();
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        playerController = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        // Potentially find a way to only seek the Shift + W button (running) to perform parkour. Just Shift is a bit... boring

        // If you want to eliminate the pressing of the space button to perform parkour, comment the next line, and uncomment the line after
        // if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && !inAction)
        if (!inAction)
        {

            var hitData = environmentScanner.ObstacleCheck();
            if (hitData.forwardHitFound)
            {
                // if there's an obstacle, determine its height, and then pick the proper parkour action based on that height:
                foreach(var action in parkourActions)
                {
                    if (action.CheckIfParkourPossible(hitData, transform))
                    {
                        // If the parkour is possible, based on the 'hitData' and the players' transform, then do it, and then break the foreach loop:
                        StartCoroutine(DoParkourAction(action));
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator DoParkourAction(ParkourAction action)
    {
        // boolean flag, to ensure this function does not keep repeating itself in the Update function:
        inAction = true;
        // when the animation is about to start, deactivate the Player's controller:
        playerController.SetControl(false);
        // set the animator mirror up (for actions, like the vault one, which require mirroring hands based on direction of approach of player):
        animator.SetBool("mirrorAction", action.Mirror);
        // Cross-fade between the locomotion and the 'Step Up' animation, for 0.2 seconds:
        animator.CrossFade(action.AnimName, 0.2f);
        // skip a frame, before cross-fading to a new animation:
        yield return null;
        // Get the state we are transitioning into (to access its time, using (animation Name).length):
        var animState = animator.GetNextAnimatorStateInfo(0);
        
        // if the designer made a naming mistake in the Parkour action, and we can't find it, throw out a Debug error stating a wrong name:
        if (!animState.IsName(action.AnimName)) Debug.Log("The parkour animation is wrong");

        // wait for the animation to end
        // yield return new WaitForSeconds(animState.length);
        
        // Timer:
        float timer = 0f;
        // if the timer is shorter than the animation state duration, update the timer, rotate the player towards the obstacle, and wait for 1 frame ('yield return null')
        while (timer <= animState.length)
        {
            // Increment the timer:
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            // Rotate the players' rotation towards the target rotation (from his 'transform.rotation', to the obstacles' 'TargetRotation', at the players' RotationSpeed, independent of frames (therefore multiply the speed with "Time.deltaTime")):
            if (action.RotateToObstacle)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, action.TargetRotation, playerController.RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            // if target matching is allowed, then match the target:
            if (action.EnableTargetMatching)
            {
                MatchTarget(action);
            }

            // stop the loop when the animation is transitioning to another animation:
            // if (animator.IsInTransition(0) && timer > 0.5f) break;
            // Wait for a frame:
            yield return null;
        }

        // wait for 'postActionDelay' seconds, when you're playing the "ClimbUp + Crouch-To-Stand" Animation combo (or any other animation with a post-Action Delay):
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(action.PostActionDelay);
        // when the animation is done, re-activate your Controller:
        playerController.SetControl(true);
        // Once we are done waiting for our animation to end, then we can resume our game:
        inAction = false;
    }

    void MatchTarget(ParkourAction action)
    {
        // if the animator is already matching its target, don't do it again lah:
        if (animator.isMatchingTarget) return;
        
        // we only want to match the y-axis (for both step-up and jump-up animations), and z-axis (for 'ClimbUp', more advanced wall climbs) values, hence x in the Vector3 input of the weight mask will be zero:
        animator.MatchTarget(action.MatchPos, transform.rotation, action.MatchBodyPart, new MatchTargetWeightMask(action.MatchPosWeight, 0), action.MatchStartTime, action.MatchTargetTime);
    }

}
```

and a copy of the problem that I keep seeing (relevant to Unity's "MatchTarget" function), everytime I attempt to climb a block:

> Calling Animator.MatchTarget while in transition does not have any effect.
> UnityEngine.Animator:MatchTarget (UnityEngine.Vector3,UnityEngine.Quaternion,UnityEngine.AvatarTarget,UnityEngine.MatchTargetWeightMask,single,single)
> ParkourController:MatchTarget (ParkourAction) (at Assets/PolygonFantasyHeroCharacters/Scripts/Parkour System/ParkourController.cs:115)
> ParkourController/d__7:MoveNext () (at Assets/PolygonFantasyHeroCharacters/Scripts/Parkour System/ParkourController.cs:92)
> UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator,intptr)

The result of this error, is that my animations do not properly match target with whatever block they are attempting to go to. I know this is an advanced topic, but I really need help

Any further information will be provided upon request

What I tried: Match Targeting my animations to the block, to get my characters' Body Parts to properly link to whatever their Parkour target is

What I got: failed Match Targeting report from the Unity game engine